# Generating a Hexagonal Lattice With Connectivity Information

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, indexing

I'm currently trying to implement a simple lattice gas simulation that involves particles bouncing around in a hexagonal grid. To start, I need to generate the grid, which is described in more detail [here](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ekimth/www-mit/laptop_backup2007/temp/18354kimt/paper.pdf). Ultimately I would like to create some sort of data structure (in Matlab or Python) that contains the coordinates of each node, as well as the identity of each of it's six neighbors (assuming it's not a boundary node).

The main issue for me is figuring out how to include connectivity. For example, suppose I find a way to index the set of all my nodes. Given some node *i*, I'd like to be able to find the index of the node say to it's right. I could just develop some consistent way of enumerating the nodes so I could calculate the indices of its neighbors, but this doesn't give me much flexibility if I wanted to generate less simple grids. What would be the best way to go about doing this? I know this is a pretty simple problem, but it's been a while since my last computer science class, so I'm pretty much only familiar with vectors/lists at this point. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with OOP in python and want customization I'd recommend simply writing the node objects yourself from scratch and implementing them similar to a doubly linked list where each node holds a reference to all of its neighbors.

If you're adamant about holding all nodes in some sort of array-like object, I would suggest a 2D array-like object with indices akin to how video games with hexagonal grids handle their coordinates.

```
n1 - n2 - n3
  \ / \  /  \
   n4 - n5 - n6
  / \  /  \  /
n7 - n8 -  n9
```

With the graph above, you can create something like `ls = [[n1,n2,n3],[n4,n5,n6],[n7,n8,n9]]`. The column index of an even row's lower right node would be its own column index, and lower left nodes would be its column index-1 (For example, `n2` is in an even row 0, to reference `n5` it would be `ls[1,1]` since `n2`'s row col index is [0,1]. To reference `n4` it would be `ls[1,0]`). Meanwhile for odd rows, its lower right node column index would be its own col index+1 and its lower left node column index being its own col index. (Example: `n5` index is [1,1] in the odd row 1, `n9` would be `ls[2,2]` and `n8` would be `ls[2,1]`).

EDIT: The way I indexed `ls` was via numpy's method of indexing. If you're using python inbuilt lists you'll need separate brackets (e.g `ls[2,1]` in numpy is `ls[2][1]` for python inbuilt lists)